# Adding webpack config to react-create-app using react-app-rewired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, yarnpkg, wavesurfer.js

Warning: I'm new to this.

I'm working on a react app that uses react-create-app via yarn.

I'm trying to install react-wavesurfer using these instructions
https://github.com/mspae/react-wavesurfer#prerequisites-and-common-pitfalls

I need to get Wavesurfer.js into the application somehow. These instructions include making changes to the webpack config, which I'm trying to avoid ejecting.

I found this react-app-rewired and this article https://jaketrent.com/post/change-webpack-config-create-react-app-without-ejecting/

So I've added this to config-overrides.js

```
const rewireProvidePlugin = require('react-app-rewire-provide-plugin')

// Use `webpack.ProvidePlugin` to add jQuery globally


module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  // add a plugin
  config = rewireProvidePlugin(config, env, {
    'WaveSurfer': 'wavesurfer.js',
  })

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            wavesurfer: require.resolve('wavesurfer.js')
        }
    }

  return config
}
```

Which builds, but I still can't access wavesurfer in the page which has these imports

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import history from '../../../history'
import Wavesurfer from 'react-wavesurfer'

import * as _ from 'lodash'

require('wavesurfer.js')
require('wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.timeline.min.js')
require('wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.regions.min.js')
require('wavesurfer.js/dist/plugin/wavesurfer.minimap.min.js')
```

When I try and run react-app-rewired start

Any clues on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the npm version instead, add wavesurfer to your package.json file under the dependencies and then do an `npm install` or if you're using yarn do `yarn install`

How to use inside project.

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
```